# Get the sum of a column that returned by an union query

Tags: postgresql

```
select count(a.serial_no) from tra_2 a where a.model_no = 'KB123' and a.flag = '3'
union
select count(a.serial_no) from stock a where a.model_no = 'KB123' and a.trans_id is  NULL
```

As a output i will get a result like

```
  4
  1
```

now i need sum 4 and 1

output should be

```
  5
```

Comment: Put it into a subquery and run `SUM` over its first column.

Comment: Where does the `1` in the desired output of `1 5` come from?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I believe those are just row numbers

Comment: @Vivek.S need to get sum in single index

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes just row numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT sum(serial_no)
FROM (
    SELECT count(a.serial_no)
    FROM tra_2 a
    WHERE a.model_no = 'KB123'
        AND a.flag = '3'

    UNION

    SELECT count(a.serial_no)
    FROM stock a
    WHERE a.model_no = 'KB123'
        AND a.trans_id IS NULL
    ) t -- alias
```

or

```
SELECT (
        SELECT count(a.serial_no)
        FROM tra_2 a
        WHERE a.model_no = 'KB123'
            AND a.flag = '3'
        ) + (
        SELECT count(a.serial_no)
        FROM stock a
        WHERE a.model_no = 'KB123'
            AND a.trans_id IS NULL
        ) AS total
```

Comment: Yeah.i used same before it shows an error  subquery in FROM must have an alias.Still in a dynamo where to use alias!

Comment: Thank u. I just came to know what the mistake i have done